# Assign member object by value: Is my hypothesis correct?

Tags: c++

I have several years experience in programming, but I am pretty new to C++. I do not completely understand what the following line will do:

```
this -> obj = MyObject(param)
```

First, I have the following hypothesis what happens:

- When calling MyObject(param), a local version of the object is created on the stack.
- This object is also copied into this -> obj.
- When the program leaves the current scope (i.e. the method in which the line is), the destructor of the local version of the object is called.

Is this correct?

Second: When this gets created, obj is created by the default constructor. When will the destructor of this object be called? I would assume, it happens right before overwriting by the above line, but my debug output indicates that it happens when this gets destroyed.

Comment: re the line in question you got it. regarding creation and destruction of `obj`, that depends on the code not shown; an assignment does not ordinarily invoke the destructor of the object assigned to (a custom assignment operator can technically do that, but it's very bad practice since it's so brittle a technique)

Comment: What is the type of obj?

Comment: Your third conclusion isn't accurate. The temp object *can* be destroyed right after the statement is finished. Some vendors seem to enjoy elongating that lifetime to scope. And whether there is anything really there *to* destroy is dependent on whether `MyObject` supports move-assignment. The destructor will fire regardless, make no mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your last assumption is wrong. The temporary (which you call local), will be destroyed right after the statement ends.
2. In the line `this -> obj = MyObject(param);`, `obj` is assigned the new *object* by *assignment operator* (effectively overwriting the members). But *overwriting* does not mean *destruction* (and in a *sane assignment operator function* destructor will not be called) . `obj` will be destroyed when `this` (parent) is destroyed (although you can explicitly destroy it if it is a pointer to something by calling `delete` on it).

Comment: Might be nice to point out that otherwise he was spot on, because that's kinda rare and he did a good job!